# Function works only in debugger

Tags: javascript, jquery

I wrote the function for check if button was clicked twice and if it was to measure the time between two clicks. It has to prevent multiple clicks in short time.

Button click:

```
$("#Save").click(function () {
    dateTime1 = new Date().getTime();
    BtnId = this.id;
    showSaveDialog();
});
```

And measuring function:

```
ButtonWasTriggeredTwice: function () {
    var result = false;
    var currentTime = new Date().getTime();
    var time = currentTime - dateTime1;
    if (PreviousBtn === null) {
        result= false;
    } else {
        if (PreviousBtn === BtnId) {
            if (  time < 1500) {
                result = true;
            }
            else result = false;
        }
        else {
            result= false;
        }
    }
    PreviousBtn = BtnId;
    BtnId = null;
    return result;
}
```

BtnId and PreviosusBtn are global scope variables.

The strange thing is this function works great when I set breakpoints in debugger. If I switch off debugger function blocks every next click on button, no matter what time interval is between clicks

Comment: when is `ButtonWasTriggeredTwice` called ?

Comment: what happens if you console.log the time datetime1 and time when using breakpoints, and when youre not using breakpoints?

Comment: @Apollo it is called in first line of function which creates popup

Comment: @Glubus console is clear, nothing shows there

Answer (score 4):

You can use this solution with unbind and timeout, like this:

HTML

```
<input type="button" id="Save" value="save me" />
```

JS:

```
function saveEventButton(){
  $("#Save").click(function () {
    alert('saved!');
    $("#Save").unbind('click');
    setTimeout(function(){
            saveEventButton();
    }, 5000); // 5sec
  });
}

 saveEventButton();
```

[This is the JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/p2sbtxfx/)

**UPDATE This solution is a mix from mine and Revish Patel solution**

```
function disableTimeout(_this){
  $(_this).prop('disabled','disabled');
  setTimeout(function(){
      $(_this).prop('disabled','');
  }, 5000); // 5sec
}


 $("#Save").click(function () {
    alert('saved!');
    disableTimeout(this);
});
```

[This is the JSfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/p2sbtxfx/1/)

Comment: I thought about it but buttons are defined in 20 files and I don't want to copy this method in each of them. So I want to call this method in one place for all buttons I want, not only save

Answer (score 0):

You can also **disable button** when you first click is performed.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  $("#Save").click(function(){
     $('#Save').prop('disabled','disabled');
     // Perform your button click operation
  });
});
```

Comment: Yes, and I have to enable it after 1.5s. And I will have to do it for about 40 or 50 buttons defined in many different files. I want to disable button in file where I have function which creates popup.

Comment: Easy way to handle with multiple button, you can use class for this.

Comment: Give common class to all button and perform single event.